# readyState is not changing to 4

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am making a chat application.In chat application, there is "Send" button, which on clicking call this javascript function.

```
    function sendmessage()
{
    var message = document.getElementById('messageBox');
    var currentuser = document.getElementById('username').value;

    if(trim(message.value) != '' && trim(currentuser) != '')
    {
        params = "mode=SendAndRetrieveNew"+
                 "&name="+encodeURIComponent(currentuser)+
                 "&message="+encodeURIComponent(message.value);
        message.value="";

        xmlHttpGetMessages.open("POST",chaturl,true);
        xmlHttpGetMessages.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlHttpGetMessages.onreadystatechange = sendmessages();
        xmlHttpGetMessages.send(params);
    }
}
```

Here variable `xmlHttpGetMessages` is an object of `XMLHttpRequest`. The `chaturl` variable contains name of a php file. This following snippet runs in that php file.

```
    if($mode == 'SendAndRetrieveNew')
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    //$id = $_POST['id'];

    if($name != '' && $message != '')
    {
        $chat->postMessages($name,$message);
    }
}
```

The `postMessages($name,$message);` is as follows:

```
public function postMessages($name, $message)
    {
        $name = $this->Mysqli->real_escape_string($name);
        $message = $this->Mysqli->real_escape_string($message);

        $query = 'INSERT INTO chat(posted_on, user_name, message) VALUES ( NOW(), " ' . $name . ' " , " '. $message .' " )';

        $result = $this->Mysqli->query($query);
    }
```

The `sendmessages()` function is as:

```
    function sendmessages()
{
    if(xmlHttpGetMessages.readyState == 4)
    {
        if(xmlHttpGetMessages.status = 200 || xmlHttpGetMessages.status == 304)
            alert("Send the message.Check database");
        else
            alert("In else of inner IF");
    }
    else
        alert("In else of outer IF "+xmlHttpGetMessages.readyState);
}
```

The `readyState` value only changes from 0  to 1, as it is evident from the last `alert();`.
How to make it's value change to 4.

After reading the first answer I changed `xmlHttpGetMessages.onreadystatechange = sendmessages();` to `xmlHttpGetMessages.onreadystatechange = sendmessages` and it worked. But the last `alert()` from `sendmessages()` is executed initially and it shows the value of readyState changing from 2,3 and finally inner `if` is executed. How function is called 3 times?
I know there is answer in comment, but I didn't understand. Pls help. I am newbie in Ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
    xmlHttpGetMessages.onreadystatechange = sendmessages();
                                                        ^^
```

The `()` means that Javascript is executing your `sendmessages` function right then and there. That function returns nothing, so essentially you're setting the `onreadystatechange` callback to be `null`.

It should be just

```
    xmlHttpGetMessages.onreadystatechange = sendmessages;
                                                        ^---note this
```

which assigns the FUNCTION ITSELF, not its results.

Comment: whoops. sorry. senior moment. meant to say JS

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me.
I also want to ask you something more. When I changed what you had told me to change, and when I checked it,I got that last `alert();` from `sendmessages()` frunction. The alert shows value changing of `readyState` as 2,3 and then inner `if` gets executed. 
How can the function run 3 times when it is called only once.

Comment: you were changing onreadystatechange INSIDE `sendmessages()`, you effectively did a recursive call. You're lucking that at some point the `if()` conditions failed, otherwise you would have had an infinite loop.